# Is it safe to use eval in javascript when it only executes server-side data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

Yes, it's a kinda duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727365/is-using-eval-for-data-from-only-server-side-safe-and-if-not-alternatives-p), but the answer given by @apsillers is a super-answer as it points a new aspect of the problem that have not been told in the previous question. Another helpful SO question that helped me to undestand better what exactly are the eval() security concerns is [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

I use eval() in my javascript code and I'm wondering if I should let it down.

Principe : I have an ajax call which initialize the first connexion between a browser client and the server. The server runs PHP. The rules is : when the client send the variable 'init' in request, on server side PHP get the contents of necessary scripts, put the content of each script as a new entry in an object (the value is the content, the name is the filename without the extension and the object is an instance of PHP STD Class), convert the whole object in JSON (by convention) and send back everything. On the client side, when the httprequest is done, Javascript get the object and do a simple for ... in () on it.

On each occurence, I have two choice : either I concat the content into a craft-made script tag and I inject it into the *head* of the HTML page. Or I eval the content (which I do now) in order to execute the code without surcharging the *head* tag. It's mostly for aesthetic.

Here is the code :

```
var xhr = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    ... //prepare the ajax request (initialize variable xhr)
}


var url = "index.php";
var params = "action=init";
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(params);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
           var o = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);


           for(s in o) eval(o[s]);


       }
}
```

My question : should I definitely avoid to use eval in this situation? Or is it safe enough (since only administrators are able to modify the scripts which are dynamically injected) ?

Comment: Sure looks like that would be running on the client.

Comment: You'd achieve the same thing if you'd use JSON.Parse. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

If older browsers are important, you could utilize a library like JQuery's $.parseJSON. see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ .  It can be quite difficult to strictly verify that the contents indeed. Of course JSON is generated at the server. But it usually contain database-data, leaving you vulnorable to JavaScript-injection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using eval() for data from ONLY server-side safe? (and if not, alternatives please)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727365/is-using-eval-for-data-from-only-server-side-safe-and-if-not-alternatives-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rule for `eval` is: a user should never `eval` a string that was generated or modified by another user. It is perfectly safe to `eval` strings created by the server. After all, the server is providing the *actual code* of the page, so if it chooses to provide that code as an `eval` string, there's not necessarily a security concern.

In terms of security, it's basically as dangerous (or basically as safe) to include a dynamically-created `<script>` element as it is to call `eval`. The only difference is that `<script>` code will always run in the global scope, while `eval` can run in the lexical scope in which the call is made, allowing it to access variables from its containing function(s). This may or may not be desirable, depending on what you expect the script to have access to.

```
function f() {
    var a = 5;
    eval("alert(a);");
    // an injected <script> wouldn't have access to `a`
}
```

The insidious danger with `eval` is that is can be quite difficult to strictly verify that the contents of `eval` have never been generated or modified by another user. In your case, if `Object.prototype` has been supplied with any enumerable property (included in your `for..in` loop), the value of that property will be `eval`ed:

```
Object.prototype.foo = "alert(1);";
```

You can get around this problem by enforcing an own-property check:

```
for(var s in o) {
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
        eval(o[s]);
    }
}
```

`eval` also incurs a significant performance penalty and creates variable-scope situations that cannot be optimized, but that's not a security concern.

Comment: So true, I didn't think about that... When the init begins, the page should be blank. Is it a way that properties set by another website, on another page of he browser, could interfer with my scripts? (I guess not). Is it possible that, on the same browser page, custom prototypes stay alive in the memory, when the user is navigating from a website to mine? Does the JSON.parse method mentioned by @realbart presents the same difficulties?

Comment: @GuillaumeFe I don't see how `JSON.parse` helps here. You're *already* using `JSON.prase` to parse the JSON, and then you need some way to execute the script strings inside the JSON. `JSON.parse` certainly won't do that for you.